# RallyAPI: How do I get a list of users for a project using the .NET api?

Tags: .net, rally

I am trying to get a list of users per project in Rally's API. It seems that putting a Project ID in the request doesn't do anything to limit the results. I seem to be getting everyone in the subscription. Neither 'WorkSpace' nor 'Project' seem to work. (I would really like to get each user per project. I know how to return a project list, but Users is a problem)

Here's what I have so far:

```
        Rally.RestApi.Request userRequest = new Request("user");
        userRequest.Workspace = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RallyAPIWorkspaceID"];
        userRequest.Project = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/XXXXXXXXX"; 
        userRequest.Query = new Query("");
        QueryResult queryUserResults = restApi.Query(userRequest);

        List<SelectListItem> AvailableUsers = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var result in queryUserResults.Results)
        {
            SelectListItem selectListItem = new SelectListItem();
            selectListItem.Text = result["DisplayName"];  // userName
            selectListItem.Value = result["_ref"]; // Reference
            AvailableUsers.Add(selectListItem);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User object in WS API does not have Project or Workspace attributes, and `userRequest.Query = new Query("Project", Query.Operator.Equals, someProjectRef)` or `userRequest.Project` will not help you to limit requests.
Maybe you want to query on [ProjectPermission](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/objectModel.sp#ProjectPermission) object. ProjectPermission inherits User attribute (a reference to a user) from abstract [UserPermission](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/objectModel.sp#UserPermission) object. This is not specific to Rally .NET or any other language toolkit.

Since ProjectPermission query cannot be bound by Project, and will return all ProjectPermission objects you will have to iterate over results and get only those you're interested in.
Unlike most WSAPI endpoints, ProjectPermissions endpoint doesn't accept any query filter. It can be a dangerous query to run because of this.For workspaces with thousands of users and hundreds of projects, hitting this endpoint can end up creating a DB query that's accessing hundreds of thousands of rows.

Comment: Thanks much. Wow, that's ridiculous on their part... I can think of a few instances where one would want to get all users for a project. RallyAPI is quite sloppy and difficult to work with in general, now this to add to the list of bummers... Thanks again.

Comment: How about, in the .Query of the request object, can I do something like: userRequest.Query = new Query("Project", Query.Operator.Equals, "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/1234567890")

Comment: Unfortunately it will not work either - I updated the answer to include that info above too. User object inherits from DomainObject that has only Subscription attribute. The Domain Object inherits from 
PersistableObject. Nowhere in this hierarchy there is a Project attribute on the object.